# Javascript Scope of "for" loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alrighty... so there's a couple things going on here. First, I'm trying to create a global object called myScrolls. Second, I'm trying to set the value of that global object inside a jQuery load function. Third, I'm trying to access the myScrolls object outside of the load object.

What am I missing? Do the 'for' loops have limited scope?
Thanks

```
myScrolls=new Object();

$(window).load(function () {

    var projectCount = 5;

    for (var i=0;i<=projectCount;i++)
    {
        var singleProject = 'project_' + i;
        myScrolls[singleProject] = new iScroll(singleProject, horizontalPreferences);
    }

});

console.log(myScrolls);
```

Comment: The parameter `horizontalPreferences` has not been declared or initialised and will throw a reference error. Also, you don't describe the error you see. Other than that noted, you should not see any error. `myScrolls` is a reference to an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to read the object before the `load` callback executes.

Comment: I think that's part of the problem, but it still doesn't work if I place `console.log` inside of the `load` callback. However, it does work if `console.log` is placed inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

That $(window).load() function is waiting until after the window loads, and because the console log is not also in that callback, it actually gets executed before the function does. Thus by the time the console statement runs, its actually not populated.

```
myScrolls=new Object();

$(window).load(function () {

    var projectCount = 5;

    for (var i=0;i<=projectCount;i++)
    {
        var singleProject = 'project_' + i;
        myScrolls[singleProject] = new iScroll(singleProject, horizontalPreferences);
    }

    console.log(myScrolls); //this was out of scope when outside of $(window).load()

});
```

Comment: Hmmm.. that still doesn't work. However, it does if `console.log` is placed inside the `for` loop. Should the entire `for` loop execute before proceeding the the `console.log(myScrolls)`?